# How to translate Magento 2 My account page

Tags: translate

im trying to translate My Account page. I was looking for CSV file but did not find any. Could you help me with this please ?

[image]

Comment: Did you installed any langauge pack ? or you are using custom theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `{Your_LanagaugeCode}.csv` at if not exits

File Path :- **app/design/frontend/{themevendorname}/{Themename}/i18n/**

**add below code at this csv file**

```
"Address book", "My Contact Details"
```

**Then do Cache flush and do the static content deploy.**

> Using This Change **Address Book** Text To **My Contact Details**

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/i18n/sk_SK.csv

```
"Edit Address","Upraviť adresu",module,Magento_Customer
"Account Information","Informácie o účte",module,Magento_Customer
...
```

<sup>note : sk_SK is for Slovaque language, code_ISO.csv</sup>

**Note:** don't forget to :

clean the cache

clean `var/view_preprocessed` content

clean `pub/static` content

deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`